# vegan dbrda species scores are empty despite community matrix provided

Tags: r, vegan, rda

I have performed "Distance based redundancy analysis" (dbRDA) in R using the vegan community ecology package. I would like to show the relative contribution of (fish) trophic groups to the dissimilarity between samples (abundance data of trophic level fish assemblages) in an ordination plot of the dbRDA results. I.e. Overlay arrows and trophic level group names onto the ordination plot, where the length of the arrow line indicates the relative contribution to dissimilarity. This should be accessible via the `vegan::scores()` function, or stored with the `dbrda.model$CCA$v` object, as I understand.

However, species scores are empty (NA) when using `dbrda()`. I understand that the dbrda function requires the community matrix to be defined within the function in order to provide species-scores. I have defined it as such, but still unable to produce the species scores. What puzzles me is that when I use `capscale()` in the vegan package, with the same species-community and environmental variable data, and formulated the same within the respective functions, species scores are produced. Is `dbrda` in vegan able to produce species scores? How are these scores different to that produced by `capscale` (when the same data and formula are used)? I provide an example of my data, and the formula used. (I am fairly confident in actually plotting the species-scores once obtained - so limit the code to producing the species-scores.)

```
#Community data matrix (comm.dat): site names = row names, trophic level = column names
>head(comm.dat[1:5,1:4])

            algae/invertebrates corallivore  generalist carnivore herbivore
h_m_r_3m_18                   1           0                    3         0              
h_m_r_3m_22                   6           4                    8        26                     
h_m_r_3s_19                   0           0                    4         0                      
h_m_r_3s_21                   3           0                    7         0                      
l_pm_r_2d_7                   1           0                    5         0   

> str(comm.dat)

num [1:47, 1:8] 1 6 0 3 1 8 11 2 6 9 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
..$ : chr [1:47] "h_m_r_3m_18" "h_m_r_3m_22" "h_m_r_3s_19" "h_m_r_3s_21" ...
..$ : chr [1:8] "algae/invertebrates" "corallivore" "generalist carnivore" "herbivore" ...

# environmental data (env.dat): Already standardised env data.
>head(env.dat[1:5,1:3])

      depth   water.level  time.in
-0.06017376   1.3044232   -1.7184415
-0.67902862   1.3044232   -1.7907181
-0.99619174   1.3044232   -1.7569890
-1.06581291   1.3044232   -1.7762628
 2.39203863  -0.9214933    0.1703884

# Dissimilarity distance: Modified Gower (AltGower) with logbase 10 transformation of the community data matrix

> dis.comm.mGow <- vegan::vegdist(x = decostand(comm.dat, "log", logbase = 10), method = "altGower")

# Distance based RDA model: Trophic level data logbase transformed modified Gower distance, constrained against the interaction of dept and water level (tide), and the interaction of depth and time of day sampled`

> m.dbrda <- dbrda(formula = dis.comm.mGow ~ depth*water.level + depth*time.in, data = env.dat, scaling = 2, add = "lingoes", comm = decostand(comm.dat, "log", logbase = 10), dfun = "altGower")

# Check species scores: PROBLEM: No species level scores available

> m.dbrda$CCA$v

      dbRDA1 dbRDA2 dbRDA3 dbRDA4 dbRDA5
[1,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA

# OR pull species scores using scores(): Also does not show species scores...

>scrs <- scores(m.dbrda,display="species"); scrs

       dbRDA1 dbRDA2
spe1     NA     NA
attr(,"const")
[1] 6.829551

# when replacing dbrda with capscale, species scores are produced, e.g.


> m.cap <- capscale(formula = dis.comm.mGow ~ depth*water.level + depth*time.in, data = env.dat, scaling = 2, add = "lingoes", comm = decostand(comm.dat, "log", logbase = 10), dfun = "altGower")

> m.cap$CCA$v[1:5,1:3]

                         CAP1        CAP2        CAP3
algae/invertebrates    0.2044097 -0.04598088 -0.37200097
corallivore            0.3832594  0.06416886 -0.27963122
generalist carnivore   0.1357668 -0.08566365 -0.06789812
herbivore              0.5745226 -0.45647341  0.73085661
invertebrate carnivore 0.1987651  0.68036211 -0.19174283
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dbrda()` function really does not get the species scores. However, if we had the following function in **vegan**, you could add those scores:

```
#' Add Species Scores to Ordination Results
#'
#' @param object Ordination object
#' @param comm Community data
#'
#' @return Function returns the ordination object amended with species
#'     scores.
#'
#' @rdname specscores
#' @export
`specscores` <-
    function(object, comm)
{
    UseMethod("specscores")
}
#' importFrom vegan decostand
#'
#' @rdname specscores
#' @export
`specscores.dbrda` <-
    function(object, comm)
{
    comm <- scale(comm, center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)
    if (!is.null(object$pCCA) && object$pCCA$rank > 0) {
        comm <- qr.resid(object$pCCA$QR, comm)
    }
    if (!is.null(object$CCA) && object$CCA$rank > 0) {
        v <- crossprod(comm, object$CCA$u)
        v <- decostand(v, "normalize", MARGIN = 2)
        object$CCA$v <- v
        comm <- qr.resid(object$CCA$QR, comm)
    }
    if (!is.null(object$CA) && object$CA$rank > 0) {
        v <- crossprod(comm, object$CA$u)
        v <- decostand(v, "normalize", MARGIN = 2)
        object$CA$v <- v
    }
    object
}
```

I don't know if we are going to have this function (with other methods),  but you can use it if you source it in your session.

Comment: Dear Jari, Thanks very much, your function works perfectly. `source("./sp_scores.R")`
`sp.scores <- specscores.dbrda(m.dbrda,comm.dat)`
`scores(sp.scores,display="species")` Result: Species scores were identical to that produced using capscale. Thanks very much, and looking forward regarding your decision.

Comment: Dear Jari, The issue you described here and in https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/issues/254#issuecomment-334071917 regarding the untransformed species data  which is currently used to calculate species scores: Would t be incorrect to add a "transform" variable into the code: `v <- crossprod(comm, object$CCA$u)` around `comm`?

Comment: It is better to use the transformation in the function call: we do not know what all transformations are usable, and having a selection of transformations in the function limits users' choice and soils function with complicated forks. So call the function as, say, `specscores(object, decostand(comm, "hellinger"))` if you used Hellinger distances.

Comment: Thanks again for your help with this Jari.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like either a bug in documentation or missing feature and I'll raise this with Jari on Github.

However, note that `dbrda()` **doesn't** have argument `comm` and hence passing this doesn't actually do anything. `comm` is for `capscale` only.

If this is a documentation bug, then it arises because we document both `capscale()` and `dbrda()` on the same page, but `capscale()` existed first and `dbrda()` only arrived later and the documentation was updated to accommodate the latter, but this may not have have been done perfectly, hence confusion about what `dbrda()` is or is not documented to do.

As it stands, the code behind `dbrda()` makes *no attempt* to compute species scores; it could, if I follow the code correctly. As such, this may just be missing functionality.

For the moment, the `NA`s are the expected result from the underlying `ordConstrained` function that implements all these models, and is what we return if the analysis was on a dissimilarity matrix, which as far as this function is concerned, it was.

Comment: In `vegan_2.5-0` the missing species scores are documented in `?cca.object` (which may not be the first place to look at). I really have not implemented species scores in `dbrda`  because I don't know if this can be correctly done (the same applies to `capscale`, but I plan to deprecate `capscale`  with its species scores). The species scores could be easily implemented copying `capscale`  code, but I'm not sure if this should be done.

Comment: Dear Gavin and Jari. Thanks for the response, and answering my question perfectly. Species scores in ordination plots are useful to diagnose the fundamental differences between assemblages. It is used in many publications using R or Primer, and books like Numerical ecology with R, suggesting greater reliance on this functionality in community ecology. Why is capscale being depreciated? (I thought it was the preferred option when covariates included factors). Are there more appropriate methods or R packages to calculate the species contribution to dissimilarity? Advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `dbrda` is supposed to replace `capscale`. Currently (in version 2.5-0 in github), it has the same functionality, except for species scores that are not implemented.